# Get Confluence html page and css via REST

Tags: html, css, confluence-rest-api

Is it somehow possible to get the complete html content of a Confluence page including styles (css?) via REST API?

I am currently using the following URL to get the content:

```
<baseUrl>/rest/api/content/<id>?expand=body.storage
```

However, the content received contains a lot of tags like

```
<ac:layout><ac:layout-section ac:type="two_equal"><ac:layout-cell><ac:structured-macro ac:name="details" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="70cc0a1a-fbbb-4c91-b090-d6aac9ffe9c7">
<ac:parameter ac:name="id">SF</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body>
```

And opening the page in the browser obviously does not look like the original in terms of formatting because the tags above are not resolved...

Any idea how to export a complete Confluence page via REST (or any other way)?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `?expand=body.view` instead of body.storage? This should return ordinary html (and CSS I guess)

Comment: Looks better, thank you! But still no css included. ```styled_view``` looks even better (css included), but the page still looks different than the original, e.g. tables, macros, etc.

Comment: Any idea how to get a combination of ```styled_view``` and ```export_view``` to have absolute links and the complete style information?